# How to remove safari's loading wheel when using Server Sent Events

Tags: html, safari, push

I'm using HTML5's Server Sent Events to push updates to my online clients. Everything works fine on Firefox and Chrome but with Safari there's a loading wheel all the time. Maybe because he detect SSE as something loading in the page.

How can I say to Safari that SSE isn't something that loads but simply a updating script so the user won't see the loading wheel after the page is really loaded?

This is the live updated html page that the client is looking at:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>SSE Tester</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>SSE Output</h1>
    <div id="result"></div> 
    <h1>Debug Console</h1>
    <div id="status"></div>   
    <script>
    //SSE si compatible
    if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
    {
        var i = 1;
        var source=new EventSource("demo_sse.php");



        //Lorsque le serveur envoie un message
        source.onmessage=function(event)
        {
            //Validation de l'origine du serveur
            if (event.origin != 'https://secure.mydomain.com') 
            {
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+= "<br><b>Oups! Looks like something went wrong!\n\nPlease contact webmaster@mydomain.com with the following error :</b><p><pre>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The Origin of the EventSource wasn\'t coming from our secure server!</pre>";
                return;
            }
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+= "#" + i + " " + event.data + "<br />";            
            i++;
        }   

        //EventListener
        source.addEventListener('message', function(e)
        {
            console.log(e.data);
            //document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+= "Message Recevied<br />";
        }, false);

        source.addEventListener('open', function(e) 
        {
            // Connection was opened.
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+= "Connection #" + i + " opened<br />";
        }, false);

        source.addEventListener('error', function(e)
        {
            if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED)
            {
                // Connection was closed.
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+= "Connection closed by the server<br />";
            }
            else
            {
                // Error.
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+= "<b>Error Connection interrupted</b><br />";
            }
        }, false);
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
    }     

    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

And there's the code of my demo_sse.php script (server side):

```
<?php
$clientLatest = "1";
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
while(true)
{
    //Retreive latest version
    $filename = "version.txt";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $serverLatest = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);

    if ($clientLatest < $serverLatest)
    {
        //Update client 
        $time = date("H:i:s");
        echo "data: Updating to Version: $serverLatest because client's Version: $clientLatest at: {$time}\n\n";
        $clientLatest = $serverLatest;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }   
    //sleep( rand(2, 7));
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Comment: It means you're hanging the UI thread.

Comment: Ok and what should I do?

Comment: Well I don't know, not a web guy :).  My point is that asking "How to remove the wheel" is asking the wrong question.  The question is "how to I prevent <whatever I am doing> from hanging the UI.  That's the problem, not the cursor animation.  And next you would probably need to give an example of exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah I think maybe my coding is wrong somewhere but I'm not sure because all the others browser (except IE ^^) is working without loading wheel

Comment: No, Ed S. the OP is just talking about the page loading indicator in Safari's address bar, not a "wait cursor".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like using javascript's timeout fonctions fixed the problem in safari. Simply timeout the script before connecting for 1000ms so the loading seems completed for safari and then connect to SSE server.

Comment: Starting long-lived requests (long-polling, SSE) after a timeout is the only known workaround I know of, a full second might be more than necessary though. (It's a shame the EventStream doesn't automatically get special handling though….)

Comment: @exomic Does this still work? I'm running Mobile Safari in IOS 7 and am still getting the loading icon. It does; however, fix the iphone's shutting down the sse connection after about a minute.

Answer (score 0):

the solution

> using javascript's timeout functions

from @exomic is in detail:

put the script from the script tag into a function and call this function via `setTimeout`

```
<script>
  //Original Javascript goes into a function
  function startEventSource() {
      //SSE si compatible
         if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
         {
             var i = 1;
             var source=new EventSource("demo_sse.php");

            // .. here are the more code ...
         }
  }
  setTimeout(startEventSource, 1000);
</script>
```

or you can use it with lambda to give some parameters to the function:

```
function startEventSource(domain, channel, statusEl, resultEl){
  // more code here
}
setTimeout(function(){ startEventSource("https://secure.mydomain.com", "demo_sse.php?channel=1", "statusA", "resultA") }, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){ startEventSource("https://secure.mydomain.com", "demo_sse.php?channel=2", "statusB", "resultB") }, 1000);
```